# Trying to read two serial streams from Cygwin (open more than one cygwin terminal)

Tags: cygwin, arduino

I'm trying to record and monitor data from two Arduinos via Cygwin since I'm having problems with VirtualBox and Ubuntu.

The problem is that I now have to Arduinos, and two USBs connected to my computer.

I'm trying to monitor and record the data, but I can't seem to open two cygwin shells.

I'm using

```
tee </dev/ttyS1 test.txt
```

to record the data. If I can open two Cygwin shells, am I able to monitor and record two serial streams from my two Arduinos?

Answer (score 0):

You can open a second Cygwin shell by typing `cygstart bash` from the first shell.